# XGBoostError:[18:46:19] D:\Build\xgboost\xgboost-1.6-1.git\src\data\data.cc:487:Check failed: valid: Label contains NaN, infinity or a value too large

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, xgboost

I am trying to use XGBRegressor for my data but keep getting the above error when doing a model.fit.

I have tried:

`np.any(np.isnan(df))`

`np.all(np.isfinite(df))`

which are both true.

I tried getting rid of the inf and null values using:

`df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)`

`df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`

but the error still occurs.

`np.all(np.isfinite(df))` is still showing true.

Most errors I found on the website says "Input contains.." and not "Label contains.."

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but I was having a similar error and couldn't figure it out. It turns out I was doing a log transform right before I tossed my data into the regressor, and I had negative values in my output that were going to infinity. I didn't catch it because I looked for NAs/infinite values before it hit the log transform part of the pipeline.